# Adding lists to a list, got TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable

Tags: python, bash, typeerror

```
biglist = []
for files in glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*.txt')):
    sublist = numpy.loadtxt(files).tolist()
    biglist.extend(sublist)
return big_matrix
```

I am trying to add lists extracted from files to an accumulator list. After around 4k iterations, I got this:

```
TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable
```

The files are text files each containing a sequence of integers (5 multiples).

I don't know why the error occurs after so many successful iteration.

Comment: Which line did you get the error? Show us the complete traceback? And maybe debug to find the file for which the issue occured and show us what is inside the file.

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./script/round1d.py", line 335, in <module>
    y_trained = combine_y("train")
  File "./script/round1d.py", line 45, in combine_y
    big_matrix.extend(matrix)
TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable`

Comment: extend if `if isinstance(sublist,list)` or else append, if your files should always have 5 elements then there is something wrong with your input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems, that one file contains only 1 number. Then `tolist` returns only a single float. A workaround is to use `reshape`:

```
biglist = []
for files in glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*.txt')):
    sublist = numpy.loadtxt(files).reshape(-1).tolist()
    biglist.extend(sublist)
return big_matrix
```